# STM32 : FatFs Library - f_mount

Tags: c, stm32, spi, fatfs

I am programming the STM32F0 (Keil uVision 5). 
I've tried to use FatFs library to manage a file system (SD card). I've writen every initialization functions and the project is compiling without any errors / warnings. But first function f_mount doesn't work properly. The function call is:

```
const char sciezka = '0' ;
FATFS *fs = (void *) 0;
fresult= f_mount (fs, &sciezka, 1);
```

Function doesn't even reach the line with disk_initialize. And I get fresult "FR_NOT_ENABLED"  (f_mount -> find_volume : : : : : after line  fs = FatFs [vol] fs pointer is still NULL). 
FatFs library with the examples is on the fatFs website :
http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/en/mount.html

Please tell me what I should do with it.

Comment: Was your problem solved? I am having same problem with f_mount function.

Answer (score 3):

Your FAFTS variable is a null pointer. Use a local variable. Like this.

```
FATFS fs;
f_mount(&fs, "0:", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the SD card specs, on STM32F407, it does supply at most 2.9-3V. When you use 5V, SD Card module works better.