# FR_Not_Enabled Fat_fs error when read sd card?

Tags: c++, c, stm32, fat32, fatfs

i am using stmf429 mcu,Ive designed the board by myself,

want to read sd card and open it but the f_mount has an error(FR_Not_Enabled).the in initialize is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help you without any further information, but maybe the following thread is helpful to you:
[STM32 : FatFs Library - f_mount](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37897576/8484720)

Comment: If this does not help you, please give additional information: show your code, which library are you using,...

Comment: I'm using FATFS_V010B, before that this program has been tested by stm32f429 discovery board and it was ok but with my board not ok, i checked the pins 100 times and it was ok and crystal has 8MHZ frequency. the initialize return is SD_OK.